# OpenId access token does not work for rest api

Tags: single-sign-on, auth-provider, open-id-connect, session-id

I want to use OpenId for Salesforce authentication.

I have done the following:

- created an auth provider (like in this tutorial: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=0)

  created a Connected App (Callback URL: my .Net Core web app; Selected OAuth Scopes: all scopes)

  wrote a .Net Core web app and I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect for OpenId

Now I test the OpenId authentication and it works. Finally I want to use the openId response access token for salesforce REST API, but it does not work. I get:

```
[
 {
    "message": "This session is not valid for use with the REST API",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
 }
]
```

Could someone tell me how I can use the openId access token for Rest API?

Thanks,
mg92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the scope parameter "[api](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&type=5)" into my scope list.

Now I can do REST API calls.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
 o.ClientId = "XYZ";
 o.ClientSecret = "ABC";
 o.Authority = "https://test.salesforce.com";
 o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
 o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
 o.Scope.Add("api");
});
```